# Always On Availability Groups and MSDTC for SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, availability-groups, msdtc

I have been told that since MSDTC is not supported for SQL Server 2012 Always On Availability Group and should be turned off.

what specific settings do I need to change to turn it off?

This is what I currently have:

[image]

Comment: Have you configured MSDTC ?

Comment: Nope, still on default setting at the moment.

Comment: Kindly explain default setting, you either set it up or you do not ?

Comment: The Local DTC on the database server has the settings in the image below: https://imgur.com/a/1rHouTH

Comment: Seems like it is enabled, you need to uncheck the network DTC access box and that should disable other boxes, if not uncheck then as well, apply and then ok. Make sure you confirm from the application team before you make any changes.